# Get value from "Bootstrap-Select"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-select

I have a selectbox and when I select the option it updates the input box with the selectbox's values. This is working with an older version of Bootstrap-Select. But in the newer version it doesn't work anymore. I am looking for a way to make this to work in the newer version. Thanks.

- Old version (working): http://jsfiddle.net/u967uwtf/
- Newer version (not working): http://jsfiddle.net/9nzcLar6/

**HTML:**

```
<select class="selectpicker Categoria" multiple="">
  <option selected>A1</option>
  <option selected>A2</option>
  <option>A3</option>
  <option>A4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="ChangeCategory" name="ChangeCategory">
```

**JS:**

```
$('select').selectpicker();

$(".Categoria").change(function() {
  f2();
});

var f2 = function(){
  $('.ChangeCategory').val($(".Categoria").val());
}
f2();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to use `Array.from()` and `map` methods in order to obtain all the selected values.

```
var values=Array.from($(".Categoria").find(':selected')).map(function(item){
    return $(item).text();
});
```

Working solution

```js
$('select').selectpicker();

$(".Categoria").change(function() {
  f2();
});

var f2 = function(){
   var values=Array.from($(".Categoria").find(':selected')).map(function(item){
      return $(item).text();
   });
   $('.ChangeCategory').val(values);
}
f2();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><select class="selectpicker Categoria" multiple="">
    <option selected>A1</option>
    <option selected>A2</option>
    <option>A3</option>
    <option>A4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="ChangeCategory" name="ChangeCategory">
```

You can do this, also, in a single line of code, using `arrow` function.

```
$('.ChangeCategory').val(Array.from($( ".Categoria option:selected" )).map(a=>$(a).text()).join(','));
```

Answer (score 1):

replace f2 with below:

```
var f2 = function(){
$('.ChangeCategory').val($( ".Categoria option:selected" ).text());
}
```